# Container access to gcloud credentials denied

Tags: windows, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-authentication, google-cloud-sdk

I'm trying to implement the container that converts data from HL7 to FHIR (https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/healthcare/tree/master/ehr/hl7/message_converter/java) on Google Cloud. However, I can't build the container, locally, on my machine, to later deploy to the cloud.

The error that occurs is always in the authentication part of the credentials when I try to rotate the image locally using the docker:

```
docker run --network=host -v ~/.config:/root/.config hl7v2_to_fhir_converter 
/healthcare/bin/healthcare --fhirProjectId=<PROJECT_ID> --fhirLocationId=<LOCATION_ID> -- 
fhirDatasetId=<DATASET_ID> --fhirStoreId=<STORE_ID> --pubsubProjectId=<PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID> -- 
pubsubSubscription=<PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_ID> --apiAddrPrefix=<API_ADDR_PREFIX>
```

I am using Windows and have already performed the command below to create the credentials:

```
gcloud auth application-default login
```

The credential, after executing the above command, is saved in:

```
C:\Users\XXXXXX\AppData\Roaming\gcloud\application_default_credentials.json
```

The command `-v ~ / .config: /root/.config` is supposed to enable the docker to search for the credential when running the image, but it does not. The error that occurs is:

```
The Application Default Credentials are not available. They are available if running in Google 
Compute Engine. Otherwise, the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS must be defined 
pointing to a file defining the credentials. See 
https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/application-default-credentials for more information.
```

What am I putting error on?

Thanks,

Comment: 1) Your assumption about `is supposed to enable the docker to search` is incorrect. Container applications cannot search the host's environment. Google ADC only checks known locations and the path your specified is not one of them. 2) Do NOT reference credential files created by the CLI `gcloud`. Specify the service account JSON file from your directory and not one managed by the CLI.

Comment: 3)  Use the container mount syntax (-v) to specify the service account file. Then set the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` (-e) when launching the container to tell it where the credentials are located.

Comment: Thank you for the help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A container runs isolated to the rest of the system, it's its strength and that's why this packaging method is so popular.

Thus, all the configuration on your environment is void if you don't pass it to the container runtime environment, like the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS env var.

I [wrote an article on this](https://medium.com/google-cloud/use-google-cloud-user-credentials-when-testing-containers-locally-acb57cd4e4da). Let me know if it helps, and, if not, we will discussed the blocking point!

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the help!! I tried the following code to start...

Comment: `SET ADC = %appdata%/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json`

Comment: `docker run --network=host -e GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json -v ADC:/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json:ro
/healthcare/bin/healthcare --fhirProjectId=<PROJECT_ID> --fhirLocationId=<LOCATION_ID> --fhirDatasetId=<DATASET_ID> --fhirStoreId=<STORE_ID> --pubsubProjectId=<PUBSUB_PROJECT_ID> --pubsubSubscription=<PUBSUB_SUBSCRIPTION_ID> --apiAddrPrefix=<API_ADDR_PREFIX>`

Comment: But is still showing error:  `java.io.IOException: Error reading credential file from environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS, value '/tmp/keys/FILE_NAME.json': File does not exist.`

Comment: I did put just:`SET ADC="%appdata%/gcloud/application_default_credentials.json"`

Comment: And using `%ADC`

Comment: Appreciated your help =)

Comment: Just another question... In `--apiAddrPrefix=<API_ADDR_PREFIX>` I'm using `healthcare.googleapis.com/v1`. Is that correct? The credentials are fine, but I'm getting the folowing error:

Comment: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:158)
at com.google.api.client.http.GenericUrl.<init>(GenericUrl.java:125)
at com.google.cloud.healthcare.apiclient.HttpFhirClient.generateFhirStoreUrl(HttpFhirClient.java:89)
at com.google.cloud.healthcare.apiclient.HttpFhirClient.getFhirStore(HttpFhirClient.java:73)
at com.google.cloud.healthcare.pubsub.MessageListener.start(MessageListener.java:70)
at com.google.cloud.healthcare.Hl7V2ToFhirWorker.main(Hl7V2ToFhirWorker.java:117)`

Comment: I just put `https://healthcare.googleapis.com/v1beta1` and it works!! Thanks